# What statistic is appropriate to test if measured data points from untrusted sources are accurate enough?

Tags: application

Suppose I'm retrieving the price of asset from 3 different independent sources.

What statistic can I use to test whether data points are close enough that I can be confident they're correct?

I have no prior information about what should actual price be at all. Also, I don't want to trust any of my sources. If many sources report similiar price, I will assume, that they're reporting correct value.

Comment: If you believe that it is very unlikely that more than one is defective then why not use the median of the three on your analyses instaed of the three original values?

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to look at methods to test for concordance as is often done when comparing raters.  There is a lot of statistical literature on this. Cohen's Kappa is a measure used in this link that shows its use with two raters but then generalizes to three or more: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3165924

If your data is numeric you can define a numerical difference x such that if the difference is less than less than x in absolute value you say the pair agree and disagree otherwise. That will make the data binary so as to be suitable for Cohen's kappa.